# OctoberCMS - Extending the User plugin's list toolbar by adding an extra button/link

Tags: octobercms

I've been extending October's [User plugin](https://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-user) with my own plugin that adds a few more fields using the method's outlined in [their docs](https://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/extending#extending-user-model).

I've also added an option to export the user data using my own controller which works just fine. The problem I'm having is kinda the "easy" bit. All I need to do is add an extra "Export" button to the list toolbar at the top of the backend list view (markup at `rainlab/user/controllers/users/_list_toolbar.htm`). I just can't seem to find any function/event that I can hijack to either add a button in or replace the entire `list_toolbar` with my own.

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author of this plugin needs to add a [view event hook](http://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/extending#backend-view-events) for extending the toolbar.

```
<?= $this->fireViewEvent('rainlab.user.extendUserToolbar') ?>
```

Otherwise you could consider adding the export link to the side navigation.

```
Event::listen('backend.menu.extendItems', function($manager) {
    $manager->addSideMenuItems('RainLab.User', 'user', [
        'export' => [
            'label'       => 'Export',
            'icon'        => 'icon-export',
            'url'         => Backend::url('path/to/your/export/controller'),
            'permissions' => ['rainlab.users.*'],
        ],
    ]);
});
```

Comment: Ok, good to know I'm not missing anything. The side menu will do just fine, cheers!